# XPAGE: dont render Panel/Repeat in html

Tags: xpages

Whenever i create a panel or a repeat control in an XPage it renders it as a div tag.
Is it somehow possible to disable the rendering of the html tag. I just want to make the response document smaller.

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For panel and repeat controls look at the `disableOutputTag` property.

For repeat controls have a look at the `removeRepeat` property.

Answer (score 0):

a panel's HTML representation is always rendered as a div as soon as you add properties like a control id or a styleClass to it. More or less the same applies to repeats: if remove the control's id in designer it will not be rendered in html. Or you could set the repeat's "removeRepeat" property to TRUE (All properties >> basics >> removeRepeat)

EDIT: ...or follow Per's reply...